# Suggestion on Splitter, service activator and header

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking for a direction on how to handle my case:

I have a top level jaxb Request object, it may contain exisisting sessionID attribute or I need to generate one. This object then contains sub-operations that are to be executed one by one. So I'll be using splitter after it. I want to get sessionID value as a header on subsequent messages with sub-operations.

In previous project, I have sent in the Request to "session service activator" first, then sent it to the splitter to generate a list of sub-operations (which inherited the headers). This could work here.
Question: is there another way to deal with this?

Suppose we had a list of operations, and after the first one, I wanted to pass on the result of the first one to subsequent ones, how to structure it?

Thanks.

[UPDATE]
Here is a simple hierarchical structure I had to deal with:

RootRequest (Session)

-SubOperation 
   -Sub Operation 
...

Here is how I implemented it:

```
...
<int:chain input-channel="rootRequestChannel"
    output-channel="operationSplitterChannel">
    <!-- Process top level request-->
    <int:service-activator id="rootRequestHandler"
        method="process" ref="rootOperationHandler">
    </int:service-activator>
    <!-- Put session id in header -->
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header
            name="#{T(ServicesConstants).SESSION_ID}"
            expression="payload.result.session" />
    </int:header-enricher>
</int:chain>

<int:splitter input-channel="operationSplitterChannel"
    ref="requestSplitter" output-channel="operationFilterChannel" />

<!-- Route the Result of Root Request to aggregator, the rest for processing to subOperataionHandler. -->
<int:filter input-channel="operationFilterChannel" ref="operationFilter"
    output-channel="subOperataionHandlerChannel" discard-channel="operationResponseOutputChannel" />

<int:service-activator id="subOperataionHandler"
    input-channel="subOperataionHandlerChannel" output-channel="operationResponseOutputChannel"
    method="process" ref="subOperationHandler">
</int:service-activator>

<int:aggregator input-channel="operationResponseOutputChannel"
    output-channel="primaryResponseChannel" method="aggregate"
    ref="responseAggregator">
</int:aggregator>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, use a `<header-enricher/>`.

First, before the splitter; all the split messages will inherit all the enriched headers.

Similarly, you can manipulate the payload and/or headers to provide whatever you want to downstream elements.

Comment: Thanks, after implementing it I like it, less complicated than I thought.